# Laravel orm Order by custom attribute

Tags: laravel-4, orm

In my user model I have added custom attribute get number of post user have created.
I can successfully get that but when I have try to order by it give error.

```
1054 Unknown column 'posts' in 'order clause'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you let us know what is the Eloquent query you're running? Also make sure that the name of the table you're using is correct.

EDIT:

Does the posts column exist in the users table? Or are you trying to get all the posts from the Post Model and order the posts by their name in descending order?

If that is what you want to do then you would need to go to your User Model and set up your relationship with posts.

In User Model create this method:

```php
public function posts() {
   return $this->hasMany('Post'); // Post would be the name of the Posts Model
}
```

In Post model do this:

```php
public function user() {
  return $this->belongsTo('User'); // Where User is the name of the Users Model
}
```

Then according to the Laravel documentation you could do someonething like this with the query:

```php
$users = User::with(array('posts' => function($query)
{
    $query->orderBy('name', 'desc'); // assuming that 'name' would be the column in the posts table you want to sort by

}))->take(5)->get();
```

I hope I am correct and this helps and that solves your issue.

Comment: User::select(array('id', 'username'))->orderBy('posts', 'desc')->take(5)->get();